# RAML Code understanding

Tags: mule, raml

I have below requirement for designing `simple RAML`. I’m newbie in `RAML` coding so would like to know if my code is according to requirement or not

**Requirement:**

- Has at least 1 endpoint with a GET and POST method.
- Includes description attribute of the API
- Includes description attribute of the method
- The GET request takes a query parameter of "mulesoft"
- Define the response with an object that contains least a string and
  integer  data type
- Includes an example for a 200 response code that matches the
  definition’s response object from above

My code:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: Coding_Champions
version: 1.0.development
baseUri: http://localhost:8004/api
description: This API displays and adds Organisation with details

types:
  Org:
    type: object
    properties:
      name: string
      address: string
      pincode: integer
/details:
  displayName: Company Details
  description: Coding challenge which takes query parameter of "mulesoft"

  get:
    description: Retrieve a list of all the Orgs
    queryParameters:
      mulesoft: 
       description: Specify the Org name that you want to retrieve
       type:    boolean
       required: true
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            type: Org
            examples:
              MuleSoft:
                name: MuleSoft
                address: 77 Geary Street, Suite 400
                pincode: 94108
  post:
      description: Add a Org to list
      body: 
        application/json: 
            type: Org
            examples:
              Cognizant:
                name: Cognizant
                address: DLF
                pincode: 9771
      responses: 
        201:
          body: 
            application/json:
              example: |
                {
                "message":"New Org updated but not really"
                }
```

I’m more of concerned with one of point in the requirement

```
"The GET request takes a query parameter of “mulesoft”
```

Does it mean I should give `mulesoft` as parameter dynamically in my `url`, If yes then other than `mulesoft` is passed as parameter then it should throw an error ?

(or)

Does it mean i need to hard code `“mulesoft”` in my `RAML` code as I have done now ?

Can you please clear me on this ?

Comment: The description for query param mulesoft shows " Specify the Org name that you want to retrieve" but type is "boolean".How can a name be boolean?

Comment: thanks for reply.. description part you can ignore.. i ended of writing something ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it mean I need to hard code “mulesoft” in my RAML code as I have
>   done now ?

Yes.You should define that in RAML as you are doing right now.Since its required parameter,its presence could be validated in implementation.

Comment: should it be boolean type ?

Comment: @Rahul, 
What would be your api request url,that you would hit for get request from client? 
   
 
A. :http://localhost:8004/api/details?mulesoft=abcxyz


B: http://localhost:8004/api/details?orgName=mulesoft





A or B?

Comment: @Rahul, 
Are you are suppose to send "True"/"false" in request.like "mulesoft=true".IF you set type as boolean,it will except the value as true/false.But if you want it to be a mandatory query param that a client must send.Then attribute "required=true",as you already have in your RAML serve the purpose.

Comment: i'm not sure on that my question was actually about it.. i am confused over that .. should it take as dynamic query param or  should i define directly in RAML

Comment: @Rahul , You should define directly into RAML, as it will help client to know what exactly needs to be send in request as a query param.If you have a concrete "key" for Query Param,its value could be checked and validated in implementation.Like if someone wants to retrieve all the orgs who use mulesoft. you can have something like "http://localhost:8004/api/details?mulesoft=true" .Yes it could be boolean.